# LibreOffice 7.0.2.2 Calc serious bug

Tags: libreoffice, 20.10

After upgrading from 20.04 to 20.10, the **LibreOffice** package was automatically upgraded to version 7.0.2.2. However, LibreOffice **Calc** has now a serious bug not present in version 6.4:

Create an empty sheet with the following in the first three rows of the first column:

```
    |  [A]
----+--------
[1] | 0
[2] | =A1
[3] | =A1+A2
```

The output will be:

```
0
0
0
```

Now, go to cell A1 and enter `1`. The output should be:

```
1
1
2
```

However,

```
1
1
0
```

is displayed temporarily. When you take another action (like minimize & restore the Calc window) then the correct output is displayed.

It seems like a refresh problem (pressing <kbd>F9</kbd> corrects it), but serious enough to mislead the user!

Can you reproduce this problem in your installation?

Comment: I can reproduce that.

Comment: Please let me know if you file a bug report so I can subscribe to it.

Comment: Isn't Ubuntu-specific, so question should be closed (sorry).

Comment: @tohuwawohu I think every software distributed through Ubuntu (Canonical) is the topic of askubuntu.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. I get the correct result and not (however briefly) the wrong one. LibreOffice 7.0.2.2.

Comment: @Jos Can you specify OS and bit-ness?

Comment: @FedonKadifeli 20.10 64-bits

Comment: @Jos I am using Gnome Xorg nvidia. You?

Comment: Gnome Xorg Intel graphics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing some more research, I found out that this is a known bug:

https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=137248

It is expected to be solved in version 7.0.3.x. Since, generally I do not like to install software outside Canonical's PPAs, I hope LibreOffice will soon be updated in the *groovy* repositories.

Comment: Today, on Ubuntu 20.10, LO was updated from 7.0.2.2 to 7.0.3.1 and as expected **this problem was solved**: https://packages.ubuntu.com/groovy-updates/libreoffice